# c: reordering TCP packets based on SEQ field

Tags: c, unix, tcp, network-programming, pcap

I processed a number of `pcap` files, extracted individual packets and arranged them in a per-flow data structure (flow table) as a list of packets. Now, since packets may arrive out-of-order, I need to re-order them accordingly. My main criteria is sequence number field from then `TCP` header; I guess this is the only way to re-order `TCP` packets?

When extracting packets from `pcap` files I already read SEQ value and stored in my per-packet structure, as well as next (expected) sequence value, as `pkt->seq + TCP_segment_size`.

Now, what would be the right approach to do this? I could sort the list of packets in a flow per SEQ value, but it will be very slow.

Also: do I need to obtain the ISN (initial sequence number) before start re-ordering? (basically the 1st packet with `SYN` bit set will have ISN in `seq` field of TCP header) The problem is that such packet may be missing (example: started capturing after handshake completed.)

How is re-ordering normally done?

Comment: `tcpflow` and `tcptrace` are two command line tools, which can reorder tcp packets from pcap files and output it to a file. If you want to do it yourself you have to capture all packets of a tcp stream, order them by sequence number, create a buffer of the necessary size (derived from the sequence numbers and the last packet length) and then fill the buffer, if no gaps are left. You can do that interleaved in parallel of course (you do not have to wait for all packets, if at least some arrive in order)

Comment: I don't see another (programmatical)  way except the one you mentioned. I could explain the way it is done by a TCP client receiving data, but it is suitable to limited amount of data, and I don't think it would fit your requirements (read _offline_ a potentially big number of packets).

Comment: @Ctx, thanks for comment. I already have TCP stream in pcaps, but I'm not sure about the right way of re-ordering the TCP packets, except just sorting it,

Comment: @000, thanks for response. Please provide your explanation, it would be helpful to understand TCP better!

Comment: @Mark A TCP client has better options to deal with this situation; it can simply discard all out-of-order arriving packets and always wait for the next in-order packet for processing. It can even avoid out-of-order packets by setting the window low. The peer will have to retransmit the discarded packets. This is not an efficient, but a simple solution. This is of course not possible if you are just eavesdropping.

Comment: Mark, @Ctx explained it while I was writing my comment. I'll try to summarize. Whenever a packet arrives in order, it is acknowledged and its payload copied in the receive buffer where it will remain until `recv()`ed. _Out of sequence packets_ are buffered as well in a different queue if the **SACK** option (Selective ACKnowledge) is supported: tell the sender that packets in a specific range have been received. Useful in high latency networks (e.g. cellular).

Comment: How are these data buffered? Out of sequence data is received and placed at its place of the buffer, that is dynamically allocated according to the max received sequence number (and limited by a given hardcoded size and of course by the window size). You don't have a window size, and don't have a different buffer for in sequence data, but you could adapt this policy to your scenario. It is some sort of _pigeon hole_ algorithm applied to packet data.

Comment: There's a certain maximum amount of un-acknowledged data that can be sent. Use that to your advantage: the packets can't be *very far* out of order.

Comment: Don't just sort by SEQ value, because it can wrap around.

Comment: @user253751,  >> Don't just sort by SEQ value, because it can wrap around.   Yes, good point. Thanks.

Comment: @user253751, how can I take advantage of un-acknowledged data? So basically for packets re-ordering, I should use both SEQ numbers and ACKs ?

Comment: @Mark You can take advantage of it because you know that the packets are approximately in order. Like, the next packet won't be 300MB ahead of the previous one. The allowed distance is called the window size. The original maximum was 65536 bytes; [TCP window scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option) allows up to 1GB. Note that since you have all the packets, you can parse them to see which window size the receiver is asking the sender to use (it will be less than 1GB).